# How to make a xtable readable?

Tags: r, xtable

I would like to get a table formatted like this:

[image]

I have used "xtable" but I don´t understand how to get it from the print(table) command:

```
   > test
% latex table generated in R 3.2.3 by xtable 1.8-0 package
% 
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrr}
\hline
& Df & Sum Sq & Mean Sq & F value & Pr($>$F) \\ 
\hline
Ws & 1 & 31680.42 & 31680.42 & 229.58 & 0.0000 \\ 
Pht & 2 & 11105.78 & 5552.89 & 40.24 & 0.0000 \\ 
Location & 12 & 58471.70 & 4872.64 & 35.31 & 0.0000 \\ 
Room & 1 & 5802.30 & 5802.30 & 42.05 & 0.0000 \\ 
Residuals & 8479 & 1170043.80 & 137.99 &  &  \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

> dput(test)

structure(list(Df = c(1L, 2L, 12L, 1L, 8479L), `Sum Sq` =    c(31680.4185499081, 
11105.7770715626, 58471.7013752211, 5802.30093225522, 1170043.80160024
), `Mean Sq` = c(31680.4185499081, 5552.88853578132, 4872.64178126843, 
5802.30093225522, 137.993136171747), `F value` = c(229.579669169041, 
40.240324191706, 35.3107546972765, 42.0477502955918, NA), `Pr(>F)` = c(3.43375691459393e-51, 
4.03894428387556e-18, 4.68524863196024e-81, 9.40518972974665e-11, 
NA)), .Names = c("Df", "Sum Sq", "Mean Sq", "F value", "Pr(>F)"
), row.names = c("Ws", "Pht", "Location", "Room", "Residuals"
), class = c("xtable", "data.frame"), heading = c("Analysis of Variance Table\n", 
"Response: Leaves"), align = c("l", "r", "r", "r", "r", "r"), digits = c(0, 
0, 2, 2, 2, 4), display = c("s", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f"))

Comment: Could you `dput()` your data.frame pls?

Comment: Also, how are you building your document?  Sweave? rmarkdown?  something else?  It may be that you need to change a chunk option.

Comment: I am using Text File

Comment: Luisa, you understand the formated table you show in *not* plain text -- there are lines and formatting. Report generation from R needs a target format, hence Benjamin question. xtable generates  LaTeX syntax that may be used to generate a PDF report, for instance through rmardown (cf knitR). I recommend you to have a look at Rstudio help about markdown.